# Is it possible to combine multiple partially fit estimators in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, distributed-computing, model-fitting

I have a lot of data and I want to parallelize estimator fitting by splitting up my data and fitting multiple estimators running in multiple threads, or multiple machines.

Some estimators provide a partial_fit API for out-of-core learning (e.g. `PassiveAggressiveClassifier` [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier))

Is it possible to have multiple estimators fit partially, and then combine their individual fits into a single estimator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using the standard API. You can just average the `coef_` and `intercept_` and that will produce a meaningful estimator. Do you want to parallelize over one core or over a network? There might be more efficient options for you, most of which will require a little more work.
There are parallel implementations of SGD, but these will probably only pay of for huge data sets. How large is your data (number of samples, number of features, sparsity)?

Comment: I want to parallelize over a network. I'm also looking at Spark and their estimators. My datasets vary; sample sizes can be a few thousands or hundreds of millions. Dimensions can range from few hundred to several thousand. At the moment I'm thinking of using Spark for large distributed datasets and sklearn + Spark for in-core learning and distributed parallel tasks such as cross validation.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. As long as your data fits into ram on a single (large) machine (get 256gb on EC2),  sklearn computation and prototyping will be faster with just sklearn. If you data becomes much larger than ram, spark is probably faster.